# Decomposition of SU(n) anticommutator

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

In $SU(N)$, the special unitary group, the algebra generators $T_a$ are hermitian and traceless. The structure constants are fixed with $[T_a,T_b]=i f_{abc}T_c$. In the fundamental representation of the group ($N\times N$ matrices) the anticommutator can be decomposed, being an hermitian operator, into its trace part and traceless part:
$$\{T_a,T_b\}=C_{ab}\mathbf{1}+d_{abc}T_c$$
with $C_{ab},d_{abc}$ two tensors.
Does this relation holds for every representation of the group?

Comment: For future reference, mathematicians don't like it when physicists conflate Lie algebras and Lie groups. You're talking about the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(N)$, not the Lie group $\text{SU}(N)$.

Comment: I also don't really understand the question. Any linear operator acting on any vector space whatsoever uniquely decomposes into a trace part and a traceless part, namely $T = \frac{\text{tr}(T)}{n} + \left( T - \frac{\text{tr}(T)}{n} \right)$ where $n$ is the dimension of the vector space.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.

Comment: No, [but still](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/221851/the-anticommutator-of-sun-generators/362009#362009) ...